# Biomedical Engineering: Applications, Basis and Communications bibtex style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a `bst` format problem about submit journal paper to the 
"Biomedical Engineering: Applications, Basis and Communications"

In recently, I found the more similarity type that the output looks like:

> 1. Batzoglou S, Jae DB, Stanley K, Butler J, Gnerre S, Mauceli E, Berger B, Mesirov JP, Lander ES: **ARACHNE: a whole-genome shotgun
>      assembler**.
>      *Genome Res* 2002, 12:177-189.

but the BME journal request type as follows:

> 1. Batzoglou S, Jae DB, Stanley K, *et al*., ARACHNE: a whole-genome shotgun assembler,
>      *Genome Res* **12**:177, 2002.

Note: the et al will occur when number of authors is more than three

---

Thus, how can I modify the currently `bst` to the correct one?

Comment: are you using their own style from the website? What is the current `.bst`?

Comment: hmm... the website doesn't support the bst file >"<, thus, it's very confused me ... hahahaha,  they just jotted the reference in manuscript.tex file .

Comment: Then don't use anything. Put `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and don't worry about it. If they were strict they would have included it.

Comment: !!! got it, thanks a lot, i will submit first... haaa